# Vite Enviroment Variable returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, vite

[image]

Hello guys, I'm new to Vite and I'm trying to use a `.env` variable to store a URL and use it with axios to get some data, but it returns `undefined` every single time. The URL is working and I get data if I don't use the `.env` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Solved, problem was my .env file was inside src folder and based on the Vite documentation the .env files should be in root.

Now its working.

Comment: Excellent point - I have been scratching my head for some time now, after following 20+ search results and failing miserably..Thank you!